# Typo3 Extbase backend module - Count records in child-table

Tags: extbase, typo3-8.x

I have a data model with two tables being connected (created using Extension Builder).

Table A contains blog posts, table B contains comments on the the individual posts.

Table B is connected to table A with a n:1 relation.

Now I want a list of blog posts that shows the number of comments for each post.

With a regular query I'd just join table B with a count and a group by statement.
Something like:

```
SELECT tableA.*, COUNT(tableB.id) FROM tableA 
LEFT JOIN tableB on tableB.foreignKey = tableA.uid
GROUP BY tableB.foreignKey
```

With Extbase query, this doesn't seem to work. There's no connection from tableA to tableB. How do I achieve this?

[Edit] I'm aware that I could just write the query statement myself. I wanted to do it using T3's query-object, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in your controller you need to fetch blog posts and pass them to your template:

```
/**
 * @var \Namespace\PostsRepository
 * @inject
 */
protected $postsRepository = null;

....

public function listAction () {
   $posts = $this->postsRepository->findAll();
   $this->view->assign('posts', $posts);
}
```

Then in your template you can display it like that:

```
<f:for each="{posts}" as="post">
    {post.title} <f:count subject="{post.comments}" /> 
</f:for>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, Michael. My problem was, that I made the relation the wrong way. I had a relation from tableB to tableA instead of the other way around. Your answer helped a lot!